# How to store mysql result as two dimensional array without the while loop?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `Products` WHERE `Reference`='$Reference'");
```

When I execute this query, I can fetch the query results and store in a 2-dimensional array using the mysqli_fetch_assoc() function.  But retrieving a specific value from a specific row of the result can sometime be confusing especially if the fetching, storing and retrieving are done inside a loop nested inside another loop nested in a loop - where there are many loop counters.

It was very convenient using the old way:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Products` WHERE `Reference`='$Reference'");
```

That way I could simply retrieve anything inside any number of nested loops using the loop counter, for example:

```
$Cost=mysql_result($result, $counter, "Cost");
```

What is the new equivalent of the old mysql_result function, so that I can directly  retrieve the results using the counter and field exactly like the deprecated way, without first having to fetch, store and eventually retrieve?

More and more I am beginning to feel as if the MYSQL improved, it is in fact the MYSQL inconvenienced.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php there are few helpful links in there how to do it the "old way"

Comment: Also, be sure to used prepared statements: http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/3455727